# image_tag often causes images to not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline

I just started using the asset pipeline correctly in rails 3, and am using the image_tag helper instead of just hard-coding `<img>`'s. At almost every page load, many of the images in the layout don't load.  If I refresh a couple times, they will load, but the result is that most of the time the page is a jumbled mess.  Has anyone had any experience with this, and how do I make it stop?

Comment: In production or in development mode?

Answer (score 0):

The image_tag *per se* doesn't do anything other than generate the `<img>` tag for you with the right path etc.  If you view the source code that is served up to the browser there shouldn't be anything significantly different between your image tags, whether they've been hard-coded or not.

When you get a page that is a jumbled mess, view source and copy the path to one of the broken images.  Construct that url fully and put it into your browser to see if you can retrieve just the image using the path given in the html image tag.  If image retrieval is patchy then it is something to do with how your assets are being served, not the rails image_tag helper.

Also look at whether there is any caching going on - perhaps some images were cached before they were properly saved and the browser has cached the fact there is a 'missing image' and future requests for that image are being broken.  Does hard-refreshing the page help to load the broken images?

Comment: hard refreshing the page does cause the images to load.  the code doesn't change, but what gets displayed on the screen does.  perhaps you could elaborate on 'how the assets are being served?'  thanks

Comment: what does your config file look like?  (development)